# How to create some kind of iterator (or artificial id) for a given set of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, iterator, counter

Sorry for the dumb title, but I simply don't know how to call it.

Here's what I want. Look at the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT xyz
)
JOIN ...
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

I want to know the initial order of the `xyz` rows when the query is over. So I thought about something like this (pseudo SQL):

```
iterator = 1;
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT iterator++, xyz
)
JOIN ...
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

So afterwards my result set will look like this:

```
iterator | some other data
--------------------------
5        | ...
1        | ...
6        | ...
8        | ...
4        | ...
2        | ...
7        | ...
3        | ...
```

So it would afterwards be possible to recreate the original order.

May you will now say: Why you don't simply use the `id` where you select `xyz`? Simple: There's no `id`. The `xyz` data is user input and I want to create an artificial `id` for that within the query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `row_number()` (which is a [windowing function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)) to assign the "iterator" that you want. This will create a sequenced number for each row:

```
select *
from
(
  select col,
     row_number() over(order by col) rn
  from yourtable
) src
order by random()
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5b2d5/2)

Comment: Thank you. Just a little problem in you SQL Fiddle: `test` always gets number 5 and `blah` gets number 1 ?! There seems to be a shift.

Comment: @BenjaminM It is because I was using an `order by col`, if you change it to `order by random()` it will change each time you run the query. See my edit and this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5b2d5/6 You just need to decide how you want the order applied for the `row_number()`

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me (I think). I want the relation between `col` and `rownumber` to be ALWAYS the same. So in your fiddle there should always be: `1 -> test, 2 -> blah, 3 -> smith, ...`. The problem I see here is the `ORDER`. I don't want to order the data, because the user input data is already ordered.

Comment: @BenjaminM if you want the `col` and `rownumber` to always be the same then you would use my first version (I edited my answer again). If the data is already ordered then you should be able to remove the `order by` that I placed and order it by the user input value.

Comment: yeah. if it's just `select col, row_number() over() rn` it works perfectly. only god knows why the `over()` can't be removed ;)

Comment: @BenjaminM the `over()` can't be removed but you can remove the `order by col` from inside of it -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5b2d5/10

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard way would be:

```
select row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
from (your query goes here) t
order by 1
```

This uses the window function `row_number()` as your "iterator".  It then returns the rows in the order specified.

Comment: A fundamental difference between the answers is that his will return the rows in a random order.  The first column will not be in sequential order.  In  this version, the first column is in sequential order, as it is in the example in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear in my question. I put a comment under bluefeet's answer, that should clear things up.