# SQL: Distinct selection that returns all rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

Ok maybe there is no SQL statement that can help me with this, so I don't know what to really call this one.

In an Access 2013 database I am working on:

All tables have fields for the `name` `address` `phone` `city` `state` `zip`

What is used as a `primary key is the phone number`, but it isn't set as the primary key in Access.

I would like to remove duplicate records from this database.

The phone number is the obvious unique identifier here, but how would I be able to retrieve all the data, sort it by phone number, and remove any records that have the phone number but keep one of them?

For the most part, I'm fairly certain that the address, name and all the other fields will match up, I just want to clean up the tables so there are no duplicates.

Comment: The question is: Which of the dup entries do you want to keep?

Comment: Any of them. It doesn't matter, they will all have the same phone number, the rest of the information can be gathered off of that. If I have to call someone and ask them for their address and stuff I don't mind that, I just don't want to go over all those contacts 1 by 1 and delete them myself manually that would take days.

Comment: you say `phone` is unique, but it isn't unique?! So you want `phone` to become(!) unique, right?

Comment: Right, what I meant was the phone will be the primary key once all duplicates have been removed

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `phone` is your pseudo primary key. means: It should become unique using the query.

For Postgres the following would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (phone)
  *
FROM your_table
```

It selects an arbitrary row for each phone number and so keeps phone numbers distinct.

Maybe there's an equivalent to `DISTINCT ON (...)` for access?

---

If you would have a REAL UNIQUE `id`identifier in the table, this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT min(id)
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY phone
)
```

---

## Got it working, maybe not perfect (the fastest query), but it's working!

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, *
  FROM your_table
) x
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(pseudoid) AS pseudoid
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, phone
    FROM your_table
  ) z
  GROUP BY z.phone
) y
ON x.pseudoid = y.pseudoid
```

### Explanation:

First (Lines 9-10):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, phone
FROM your_table
```

this gives you a pseudo_id for every row (plus the phone number). so we have duplicate entries, but every entry has its unique pseudoid. then (Lines 7-12):

```
SELECT MIN(pseudoid) AS pseudoid
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, phone
  FROM your_table
) z
GROUP BY z.phone
```

This makes our phone numbers unique and always selects the MIN(pseudoid). Then (Lines 3-4):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, *
FROM your_table
```

Create a pseudoid for the WHOLE table.

Then we join those tables: This gives us for every phone number the complete row (+ pseudoid) with the smallest pseudo id.

### A bit smaller (and maybe faster):

```
WITH pseudo_id_table AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pseudoid, * FROM your_table)
SELECT *
FROM pseudo_id_table x
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(pseudoid) AS pseudoid
  FROM pseudo_id_table
  GROUP BY phone
) y
ON x.pseudoid = y.pseudoid
```

Comment: Ok so if I export/reimport the table and add a primary key that should make it so I can use that query?

Comment: yeah, then this query would work. usually every(!) table should have a real unique identifier (except for many-to-many join tables). But there's for sure a query, that will fit your needs... I'm still thinking about it ;)

Comment: YOU'RE AWESOME! Thanks a lot!! I felt my brain grow from this lol! No but seriously you are awesome for this I can't thank you enough! I wish I could upvote your answer

Comment: You're welcome. I even created a smaller (and maybe faster) version of the query, that just creates the pseudo_id_table one(!) time.

Comment: You can also have a look at my question from yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126254/how-to-create-some-kind-of-iterator-or-artificial-id-for-a-given-set-of-rows). They taught me to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` ;-)

Comment: I'm going to go with export/import all the tables and apply a primary key to them. This way in the future I avoid this altogether.

Comment: I assume that `phone` is a varchar or something like this. Then it's of course better to have a separate `id` which should be an integer. This makes relations inside the database more easy and `JOIN` operations faster. But also keep in mind to set the `phone` column `unique`. This will make loopups on `phone` faster and it will prevent problems with duplicate entries. But I think, that you have to import/export the table a second time for that. But it's worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah it is. It's just the way this database is used. The applications require text fields, text tables... It's really frustrating because exporting from the application into the database causes all kinds of errors if I try to use date/time and integer, can't convert the types on import so I have to use SQL to convert.

Comment: In my side job, we had a similar situation. We had an old (non-normalized, totally crappy, fully of text/varchar/etc., NO(!) foreign keys (they are all managed inside the software), etc.) database and are now building a new application and a new database. So we have written a tool that takes and analyzes the old data and puts it inside the new database. It takes about 1 hour to run :-D But it's worth it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler approach:

1. Copy the table (structure only)
2. Make the phone the primary key
3. Append the data from the old table to the new. Any duplicate records will reject on the append.
4. Delete the old table
5. Rename the new table to the old table name

This only works if it truly does not matter which record you keep.

Comment: Ohh so take the table copy the field structure into a new empty table, assign phone as primary key and then bam! append and it will automatically dedupe. That's nice to know, it really doesn't matter what record it keeps. For the most part from using this data they are all pretty accurate just not 100%